# How to use for each and dataflow to copy excel file from Azure data lake to Azure SQL database?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I am having an excel file below which doesn't have column name for the first column.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lI7VA.png)

I need to export this file from the data lake to the SQL database. I am getting the same format of excel file every day in my data lake.

I tried with dataflow, however, I am getting an error of "Read excel files with different schema is not supported now in Dataflow"

As per the documentation suggestion, foreach and dataflow are to be used for this issue.

I have tried for each but had no success. I am new to Azure. So not sure which method I should use? I have used copy activity, but was not able to get the first column which doesn't have the column

Can anyone advise how to solve this issue, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dataflow with source as your Data lake excel (first row as header as unchecked), then add a filter where filter condition should eliminate the first row and then finally using the sink as Azure SQL Database. Below is the screenshot of something you can configure:

[image]

In filter setting, just write any condition that will skip the first row as highlighted in the screenshot above.